# use reduce to group date to make date_from and date_to

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs

How to transform this kind of structure

```
[
    {date_from:'15-6-2017'},
    {date_from:'16-6-2017'},
    {date_from:'17-6-2017'},
    {date_from:'29-6-2017'}
    {date_from:'30-6-2017'}
]
```

to this?

```
[
    {id:1,date_from:'15-6-2017',date_to:'17-6-2017'},
    {id:2,date_from:'29-6-2017',date_to:'30-6-2017'}
]
```

luckily the order is already correct, what's pop in my mind is reduce, I'm still stuck. I'm using moment.

Comment: What's the logic to set date_to date?

Comment: Where should the data `id` (auto increment possible) and the `date_to` come from?

Comment: @daan.desmedt index? it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Firemen26 if the date has no date on the next day

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution to your code, you can add formatting as you want to your date.

```js
let string = [{
    date_from: '15-6-2017'
  },
  {
    date_from: '16-6-2017'
  },
  {
    date_from: '17-6-2017'
  },
  {
    date_from: '29-6-2017'
  },
  {
    date_from: '30-6-2017'
  }
];

//split them and pull out any white spaces from beginning and end
let dates = string.map(s => {
  s = s.date_from.trim();
  let nums = s.split('-');
  let d = new Date(nums[2], nums[1], nums[0]);
  return {
    date: d,
    string: s
  };
});
let currentStart = dates[0];
let result = [];
for (let i = 1; i < dates.length; i++) {
  let {
    date,
    string
  } = dates[i];
  //If last date, add range
  if (i == dates.length - 1) {
    console.log("hello");
    result.push({
      start: currentStart.string,
      end: string
    });
  } else {
    let prevDate = dates[i - 1] || currentStart; //in case prevDate is undefined
    let nextDate = dates[i + 1];
    let diff = nextDate.date.getTime() - date.getTime();
    if (diff > (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) {
      result.push({
        start: currentStart.string,
        end: string
      });
      currentStart = nextDate;
    }
  }
}

console.log(result, 'result');
```

this is the codepen of the code so you can edit it anytime. [demo](https://codepen.io/MehulJoshi/pen/XgKaGJ?editors=0010#0)

Comment: great work but I can't use this, I need to use moment to avoid long code.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it could be done quite easily with reduce:

```js
var dates = [
    {date_from:'15-6-2017'},
    {date_from:'16-6-2017'},
    {date_from:'17-6-2017'},
    {date_from:'29-6-2017'},
    {date_from:'30-6-2017'}
];

var toT = (d)=>Date.parse(d.split('-').reverse().join('/'))

var out = dates.reduce((newArr,d,i)=>{
  if (i==1) newArr = [{id:1,date_from:newArr.date_from,date_to:newArr.date_from}];
  var prevD = newArr[newArr.length-1].date_to;
  if (toT(prevD) + (24*60*60*1000) == toT(d.date_from)) newArr[newArr.length-1].date_to = d.date_from;
  else newArr.push({id:newArr.length+1,date_from:d.date_from,date_to:d.date_from})
  return newArr;
})

console.log(out)
```

Comment: what does 

`var toT = (d)=>Date.parse(d.split('-').reverse().join('/'))` do?

Comment: Getting the timestamp from your date format, made it into a separate function to shorten the code.

Comment: I got this line of undefined error var prevD = newArr[newArr.length-1].date_to;

Comment: That's strange, you got this error inside provided snippet? if yes, then try transpiling code to non-ES6 with [BABEL](https://babeljs.io/repl/)

Answer (score 1):

You could just check the difference from the last day and insert a new object if the difference is not equal to one.

Basically it tries to get the last date drom the result array and if it is not set, it uses an empty object. Then it takes the value of `date_to` property and convert the value to a `moment` object for later comparison with `date_from`.

After a check with a needed difference by one day, `date_from` property gets an update. If the difference is not qual to one, a new object is added to the result set.

```js
var data = [{ date_from: '15-6-2017' }, { date_from: '16-6-2017' }, { date_from: '17-6-2017' }, { date_from: '29-6-2017' }, { date_from: '30-6-2017' }],
    id = 1,
    grouped = data.reduce(function (r, o) {
        var last = moment((r[r.length - 1] || {}).date_to, 'D-M-Y');

        if (moment(o.date_from, 'D-M-Y').diff(last, 'd') === 1) {
            r[r.length - 1].date_to = o.date_from;
        } else {
            r.push({ id: id++, date_from: o.date_from, date_to: o.date_from });
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: elegant solution, didn't thought of using r.length - 1. Great if you can explain step by step how does it work.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to be something like this:

```
var setToDate = function(dateStr, days) {
  var d = dateStr.split('-')
  var date = new Date(d[2], d[1], d[0])
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return date.getDate() + '-' + date.getMonth() + '-' + date.getFullYear();
}

var arr = [
    {date_from:'15-6-2017'},
    {date_from:'16-6-2017'},
    {date_from:'17-6-2017'},
    {date_from:'29-6-2017'},
    {date_from:'30-6-2017'}
]

for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i].id = i+1;
    arr[i].date_to = setToDate(arr[i].date_from, 1);
}

console.dir(arr)
```

Comment: what? do you even understand the question?

Comment: @AlanJenshen check now